# css: Image after li element goes to new line

Tags: css, list, html-lists, line-breaks

I've a problem with inserting an image after every element in my list. I used ":after" and it shows me the image but instead of after every element, the images are with a new linebreak under every element:

Should be (|=image):
Site1 | Site2 | Site...

Reality:
Site1 Site2 Site3
|     |     |

Following my css code, maybe someone can help:

```
/* Navigation */
#nav {
    position:relative; 
    height:70px;
    background:#191919;
    position:relative;
}

/* The main menu */
.menu{
    list-style: none; 
    position: relative; 
    float: left; 
    display: block; 
    left: 50%;
    padding-top:20px;
 }

/* First level of navigation */ 
.menu li{
    position: relative; 
    float: left; 
    display: inline; 
    right: 50%;
    padding-right:15px;
      }

.menu li a{
    display:inline;
    width:auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-shadow: none; 
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
     }

.menu li:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    background: transparent url('../images/nav_bar_line.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `absolute` position for this. Write like this:

```
.menu li:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:-5px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    background: transparent url('../images/nav_bar_line.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: thx, but there are still some problems..Some lines are in the text ect..
but it's better then before ;)